# pkg_resources.resource_filename is not extracting files

Tags: python-3.x, setuptools, egg, python-egg-cache

I want to package a project that contains (and uses) template html files and distribuite it as an egg.  Since I’m using tornadoweb, which requires file paths to point to html files, I can’t access the resources via stream and I really need the html files to be extracted when my program is running.

I’m having a look at setuptools and  according to `resource_filename` docs (bold is mine):

> Sometimes, it is not sufficient to access a resource in string or stream form, and a true filesystem filename is needed. In such cases, you can use this method (or module-level function) to obtain a filename for a resource. **If the resource is in an archive distribution (such as a zipped egg), it will be extracted to a cache directory, and the filename within the cache will be returned. If the named resource is a directory, then all resources within that directory (including subdirectories) are also extracted**. If the named resource is a C extension or “eager resource” (see the `setuptools` documentation for details), then all C extensions and eager resources are extracted at the same time.

Which seems exactly what I need. However this is not what happens on my machine. My `setup.py` contains the following line:

`data_files = [('html', ['html/index.html'])]`

And `index.html` is actually included in my egg file. When  I run `python3 setup.py install` my project gets installed as a single zipped egg file. Unfortunately, when my program executes the following line:

`html_path = resource_filename(__name__, "html")`

I get the following return value:

`/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/myproj-0.1-py3.2.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/html/`

The problem is that `myproj-0.1-py3.2.egg` is actually a zip file so this is not a valid path.

It’s strange because  if I call `pkg_resources.get_cache_path(‘myproj’)` I get the following path back:

`/root/.python-eggs/myproj-tmp`

But nothing is extracted there (yes, I’m running the program as root, but I’m just testing it).

Any idea why my `html` directory is not extracted?

Comment: could you provide a minimal example: `setup.py`, `html/index.html`, `print_filename.py` files (e.g., as [gist](https://gist.github.com/)) that reproduces your issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the cause of the issue. As @erykson noted I was using the wrong directory.

After replacing

`html_path = resource_filename(__name__, "html")`

with

`html_path = resource_filename(Requirement.parse("myproj"), "html")`

everything works fine.

Comment: does it mean that `resource_filename("myproj", "html")` fails in your case?

Comment: `resource_filename(Requirement.parse(__name__), 'html')` also works if you don't want to specify `myproj`