# pkg_resources doesn't extract files from python egg

Tags: python, egg, pkg-resources

I created a python egg by running `python setup.py bdist_egg` from this folder:

```
SensorDisplay/
--- sensor_display/
----- __init__.py
----- can.py
----- sensor_display.py
----- data/
--------- sensor_param.txt
--- setup.py
```

in file `setup.py`, I have:

```
 package_data = {'' : ['*.txt']},
 scripts = ['sensor_display/sensor_display.py','sensor_display/can.py']
```

and in file `sensor_display.py`:

```
PARAM_FILE = "data/sensor_display.txt"
param_file = pkg_resources.resource_filename("sensor_display", PARAM_FILE)
f = open(param_file,"r")
```

I obtain then the egg file `SensorDisplay-0.1-py2.7.egg` in folder `SensorDisplay\dist\`. However, when I install the egg with easy_install and run the file `C:\Python27\Scripts\sensor_display.py`, I obtain the following error:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\
\sensordisplay-0.1-py2.7.egg\\EGG-INFO\\scripts\\data\\sensor_param.txt'
```

It seems function `resource_filename` doesn't extract the egg-file because the filename returned considers the egg-file as a directory which it is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem, I replaced

```
PARAM_FILE = "data/sensor_display.txt"
param_file = pkg_resources.resource_filename("sensor_display", PARAM_FILE)
```

with

```
PARAM_FILE = "sensor_display/data/sensor_display.txt"
param_file = pkg_resources.resource_filename(pkg_resources.Requirement.parse("SensorDisplay"), PARAM_FILE)
```

see also [pkg_resources.resource_filename is not extracting files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22381146/pkg-resources-resource-filename-is-not-extracting-files)

Answer (score 1):

egg file is a zip archive. You can look at the contents using unzip command.